# Support for Overloaded operations in web service

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I'm trying to generate stub classes with the following:

```
wsimport -verbose -p "com.bla"  http://example.org/whatever?wsdl
```

And getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] binding operation "SSOCustomerRegister" must specify a name for its input message line 2049 of ...
```

There seems to be two operations with the same name in the wsdl.
Line 2049 is the first line of this code:

```
<wsdl:operation name="SSOCustomerRegister">
  <soap:operation soapAction="....../SSOCustomerRegister" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="SSOCustomerRegister">
  <soap:operation soapAction="......./SSOCustomerRegisterLogin" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input name="SSOCustomerRegisterLogin">
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="SSOCustomerRegisterLogin">
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I have also trying using Apache Axis eclipse plugin to generate the code and get a similar error.

The service that generates the wsdl is using .NET.

Is this an issue with the wsdl defination?
Is operation overloading supported?
Does the spec specify that you must provide input/output names when an operation is overloaded? See [here](https://www.java.net/node/667815).